# The Assignment Problem, a NumPy function?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, combinatorics

Since an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) can be posed in the form of a single matrix, I am wondering if NumPy has a function to solve such a matrix. So far I have found none. Maybe one of you guys know if NumPy/SciPy has an assignment-problem-solve function?

**Edit:** In the meanwhile I have found a Python (not NumPy/SciPy) implementation at http://software.clapper.org/munkres/. Still I suppose a NumPy/SciPy implementation could be much faster, right?

Comment: What a shame it was not implemented with numpy. Not only might it be faster, but the algorithm must be much easier to express with numpy as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, NumPy contains no such function. Combinatorial optimization is outside of NumPy's scope. It may be possible to do it with one of the optimizers in `scipy.optimize` but I have a feeling that the constraints may not be of the right form.

[NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) probably also includes algorithms for assignment problems.

Comment: There is an implementation `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment` from scipy version 0.18.

Answer (score 17):

There is now a numpy implementation of the munkres algorithm in scikit-learn under [sklearn/utils/linear_assignment_.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/linear_assignment_.py) its only dependency is numpy. I tried it with some approximately 20x20 matrices, and it seems to be about 4 times as fast as the one linked to in the question. cProfiler shows 2.517 seconds vs 9.821 seconds for 100 iterations.

Comment: This will be included in scipy as `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment` from version 0.18.

Comment: The linear_assignment_ module is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed from 0.23. Use scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment instead.

Answer (score 9):

I was hoping that the newer `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment` would be fastest, but (perhaps not surprisingly) the [Cython library](https://github.com/jfrelinger/cython-munkres-wrapper) (which does not have pip support) is significantly faster, at least for my use case:

UPDATE: using `munkres` v1.1.2 and `scipy` v1.5.0 achieves the following results:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment; import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0); c = np.random.rand(20,30)" "a,b = linear_sum_assignment(c)"
10000 loops, best of 5: 32.8 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "from munkres import Munkres; import numpy as np;  np.random.seed(0); c = np.random.rand(20,30); m = Munkres()" "a = m.compute(c)"
100 loops, best of 5: 2.41 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment; import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0);" "c = np.random.rand(20,30); a,b = linear_sum_assignment(c)"
5000 loops, best of 5: 51.7 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "from munkres import Munkres; import numpy as np;  np.random.seed(0)" "c = np.random.rand(20,30); m = Munkres(); a = m.compute(c)"
10 loops, best of : 26 msec per loop
```

Comment: I just tried the library for my case and got 25x speedup using the Cython version!

Comment: I also tried the cython version and got a massive speedup. Just had to learn to install from source since it apparently lacks pip support

Comment: The implementation of `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment` has [been revised](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/10296) and implemented from scratch in C++. The new implementation will be available in SciPy 1.4.0 and should provide substantial improvements in speed.

Comment: Yes..Newer implementation of `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment` is very fast. A `1000 x 1000` cost matrix takes 70ms to solve.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another fast implementation, as already hinted by @Matthew: `scipy.optimize` has a function called `linear_sum_assignment`. From the docs:

> The method used is the Hungarian algorithm, also known as the Munkres or Kuhn-Munkres algorithm.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html

Answer (score 2):

There is an implementation of the [Munkres' algorithm](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hungarian/0.2) as a python extension module which has numpy support. I've used it successfully on my old laptop. However, it does not work on my new machine - I assume there is a problem with "new" numpy versions (or 64bit arch).

Answer (score 2):

As of version 2.4 (released 2019-10-16), NetworkX solves the problem through `nx.algorithms.bipartite.minimum_weight_full_matching`. At the time of writing, the implementation uses SciPy's `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment` under the hood, so expect the same performance characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solver in `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment` already mentioned in some of the other answers, SciPy (as of 1.6.0) also comes with a sparsity-friendly solver in [`scipy.sparse.csgraph.min_weight_full_bipartite_matching`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.min_weight_full_bipartite_matching.html).

```py
In [2]: from scipy.sparse import random
In [3]: from scipy.sparse.csgraph import min_weight_full_bipartite_matching
In [4]: from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

In [15]: sparse = random(1000, 1000, density=0.01, format='csr')
In [16]: %timeit min_weight_full_bipartite_matching(sparse)
3.84 ms ± 12.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [17]: dense = sparse.toarray()
In [18]: %timeit linear_sum_assignment(dense)
18.8 ms ± 291 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```