# Hungarian algorithm in Python

Tags: python, graph, combinatorics, matching

Is there good implementation of Hungarian algorithm in standard python libraries?

Comment: How about http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hungarian/ ? Or maybe http://pypi.python.org/pypi/munkres/1.0.5.2

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm#Implementations?

Comment: SO question with more links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398822/the-assignment-problem-a-numpy-function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just tried:

```
pip install munkres
```

and it worked. [Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/munkres) you can find a short explanation on how to use it.

I got an error trying to install "hungarian".

Answer (score 8):

**There are multiple Options:**

```
pip install munkres
```

[Documentation here](https://pypi.org/project/munkres/)

```
pip install hungarian
```

[Documentation here](https://pypi.org/project/hungarian/)

```
pip install scipy
scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment
```

[Documentation here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html)

Answer (score 5):

Check this [munkres](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/munkres/1.0.5.4) out

Answer (score 1):

Munkres is the Hungarian algorithm in Python.

1. How to install it:

   ```
   pip install munkres
   ```
2. How to use it:

   ```
   from munkres import Munkres
   mnkrs = Munkres()
   matrix = []

   for i, val1 in enumerate(data1):
       for j, val2 in enumerate(data2):        
          if len(matrix) < i+1:
             matrix.append([])
          if len(matrix[i]) < j+1:
             matrix[i].append([])
          matrix[i][j] = val2 - val1 # or whatever you want to compare

   if matrix:
       best_idxs = mnkrs.compute(matrix)
       for (k, l) in best_idxs:
          print(data1[k], data2[l])
   ```