# Maximum Weight / Minimum Cost Bipartite Matching Code in Python

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, graph

I'm searching for Python code for maximum weight / minimum cost matching in a bipartite graph.  I've been using the general case max weight matching code in NetworkX, but am finding it too slow for my needs.  This is likely due to both the fact that the general algorithm is slower, and the fact that the NetworkX solution is implemented entirely in Python.  Ideally, I'd like to find a some Python code for the bipartite matching problem that wraps some C/C++ code, but right now, anything faster than the NetworkX implementation would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have any specific pseudo code in mind?  Can you provide a python input/output example?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075669/hungarian-algorithm-in-python

Comment: @Kevpie I'm open to almost any interface.  The maximum weight problem is, itself well defined (on Wikipedia for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs) so I didn't want to waste space redefining it.  The input would be a graph or even just a weight matrix, and the output would be a matching between the bipartite vertices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some further investigation, I've found the following two modules particularly helpful (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyLAPJV/0.3 and http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hungarian).  They are both algorithms implemented in C++ with Python bindings, and run much faster than the NetworkX matching implementation.  The pyLAPJV implementation, however, seems to be a bit too fickle for my needs and doesn't properly handle identically weighted edges well.  The hungarian module (though supposedly slower than the pyLAPJV algorithm) runs about 3 orders of magnitude faster than the NetworkX implementation on the data sizes I'm currently dealing with. I'm also going to give another look at the code suggested by kunigami, as I believe that it can be run though Shedskin fairly easily to give a reasonably fast implementation.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried scipy implementation of the Hungarian algorithm, also known as the Munkres or Kuhn-Munkres algorithm?

[scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html)

Comment: The SciPy implementation is (as of 1.4.0) based on shortest augmenting paths instead (and much faster than it was in 1.3.0).

Answer (score 3):

When you say "minimum cost matching", I assume that you mean the problem of finding the matching with lowest cost among all maximum matchings.

As of version 2.4 (released 2019-10-17), NetworkX does handle the bipartite case specifically with [`nx.algorithms.bipartite.minimum_weight_full_matching`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.matching.minimum_weight_full_matching.html).

Under the hood, it relies on [`scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html). As of version 1.6.0, SciPy also ships with [`scipy.sparse.csgraph.min_weight_full_bipartite_matching`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.min_weight_full_bipartite_matching.html) which does the same thing but for sparse inputs, and which can offer performance improvements for sparse graphs.

Comment: but that algorithm requires a complete bipartite graph which may become an issue if you have a very large and very sparse bipartite graph for which the minimum weight maximal matching shall be determined.

Comment: @user2961818: Right, I've added a note on an alternative approach for sparse inputs. When NetworkX bumps the SciPy dependency to 1.6, it could make sense to simply swap which solver to use, or make it configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this is what you are looking for, but it is a python implementation of the Hopcroft-Karp bipartite graph matching algorithm. If not, it can probably be a good starting place for you.

[Hopcroft-Karp Bipartite Matching](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/123641-hopcroft-karp-bipartite-matching/)

Comment: Thanks for the link Nico. However, the maximum matching problem is dffeent than the maximum weight matching problem; it is concerned with finding the maximum number of participating vertices, gut does not take the weights isnto account.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum weight bipartite matching can be solved by the Hungarian algorithm ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)). The link in wikipedia links to a [python](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF441/INF441b/code/kuhnMunkres.py) implementation. I'm not sure if it's faster than the code you mentioned, though.