# Match every point in two different sized sets with minimum total line length

Tags: algorithm

I have two sets of points plotted in a coordinate system. Each point in a set must be matched to *at least* one point at the other set, in a way that the sum of the length of the lines drawn by joining those points should be as low as possible. To make it clear, line drawing is just an abstraction, the actual output is just the pairs of points that must be matched.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174779/how-to-find-the-minimum-cost-of-linking-two-sets-of-points) about a similar problem, except that in my case there's no single-link restriction since the sets may have different sizes. Is there any kind of problem that describes this situation? More specifically, what algorithm could I use to solve this, assuming each set may have a maximum of 10 points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Algorithm

You can model this as a network flow problem.

By having a source of 1 at each point in the first set, and a sink of 1 at each point in the second set, plus an extra node 'dest' for any left over capacity, any valid flow will always connect every point.

Make edges between the points with cost according to the distance between the points.

So far we have a network whose solution will be the lowest cost matching of set 1 to set 2 (i.e. each point will have a single link).

To allow multiple links you can simply make the following additions:

1. add 0 weight edges between each point in set2 and 'dest' (this allows points in set 2 to be multiply connected)
2. add 0 weight edges between 'dest' and each point in set2 (this allows points in set 1 to be multiply connected)

### Example Python code using Networkx

```
import networkx as nx
import random

G=nx.DiGraph()

set1=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
set2=['a','b','c']
# Assume set1 > set2 (or swap sets)
assert len(set1)>=len(set2)

G.add_node('dest',demand=len(set1)-len(set2))
A=[]
for person in set1:
        G.add_node(person,demand=-1)
        G.add_edge('dest',person,weight=0)
        for project in set2:
                cost = random.randint(1,10) # Assign appropriate costs here
                G.add_edge(person,project,weight=cost) # Edge taken if person does this project

for project in set2:
        G.add_node(project,demand=1)
        G.add_edge(project,'dest',weight=0)

flowdict = nx.min_cost_flow(G)
for person in set1:
        for project,flow in flowdict[person].items():
                if flow:
                        print person,'->',project
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a discrete optimization approach ([Integer Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming)).

We have two sets A, of size X, and B, of size Y. This means a maximum of X*Y links, each described by a boolean variable: L(i,j) = L(Y*i+j) is 1 if nodes A(i) and B(j) are linked, 0 if not. If X = Y = 10, we can write link L(7,3) as L73.

We can rewrite the problem like this:

Node A(i) has at least one link: X (say, ten) criteria with i from 0 to X-1, each of them comprised of Y components:

```
    L(i,0)+L(i,1)+L(i,2)+...+L(i,Y-1) >= 1

Node B(j) has at least one link, and there are Y criteria made up of X components:

    L(0,j)+L(1,j)+L(2,j)+...+L(X-1,j) >= 1
```

The minimal cost requirement becomes:

```
cost = SUM(C(0,0)*L(0,0)+C(0,1)*L(0,1)+...+C(9,9)*L(9,9)
```

With these conventions, we can easily build the matrices for an ILP problem, that can be passed to our favorite ILP solving package or library (C, Java, Python, even PHP).

====

A self-contained "greedy" algorithm which is **not** guaranteed to find a minimum, but is reasonably quick and *should* give reasonable results unless you feed it a pathological data set, is:

```
- connect all points in the smaller set, each to its nearest point in the other set.
- connect all unconnected points remaining in the larger set, each to its
  nearest point in the first set, whether it's already connected or not.
```

As an optimization, you can then enumerate the points in the larger data set; if one of them (say A) is singly connected to a point in the first data set (say B) which is multiply connected, and is not its nearest neighbour C, you can switch the link from A-B to A-C. This takes care of one of the simplest problems that may arise from the "greediness" of the algorithm.

Comment: I've never heard of integer programming before. It's interesting, but I think I'll try Rivaz's approach first.
On a side note, my temporary solution is exactly like the greedy algorithm you described, but without those optimizations. I'll take a look into that too.