# Making certain matches impossible in assignment problem (Hungarian algorithm)

Tags: python, scipy, hungarian-algorithm, assignment-problem

#### Motivation:

I'm using scipy's python implementation of hungarian algorithm
(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html#scipy-optimize-linear-sum-assignment)
for matching two sets of time events.
So far so good, but I have a time difference limit (let's say 0.1s)
for matching these events and I don't want any matches which would have time
difference above this limit.

#### An example without any time difference limit:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Event:
    t: float

expected = [Event(0), Event(1), Event(2)]
detected = [          Event(1), Event(2), Event(3)] # shifted to show
                                                    # time matching

def tdiff(e1: Event, e2: Event) -> float:
    return abs(e1.t - e2.t)

cost_matrix = [
    [
        tdiff(e1, e2)
        for e2 in detected
    ]
    for e1 in expected
]
print('cost matrix:')
for row in cost_matrix:
    print('[', ', '.join(map(str, row)), ']')

row_idx, col_idx = linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix)
for i, j in zip(row_idx, col_idx):
    exp_ev = expected[i]
    det_ev = detected[j]
    td = cost_matrix[i][j]
    print('matches %s and %s, tdiff: %.3f' % (exp_ev, det_ev, td))
```

This prints:

```
cost matrix:
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 1, 0, 1 ]
matches Event(t=0) and Event(t=1), tdiff: 1.000
matches Event(t=1) and Event(t=2), tdiff: 1.000
matches Event(t=2) and Event(t=3), tdiff: 1.000
```

This is clearly not what I want, because all matches are above the limit
(0.1s).

#### What have I tried:

My solution is to artificially increase cost of "unwanted" matching in the
cost matrix, and then I filter matches to return only "wanted" matches:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Event:
    t: float

TDIFF_MAX = 0.1
expected = [Event(0), Event(1), Event(2)]
detected = [          Event(1), Event(2), Event(3)] # shifted to show
                                                    # time matching

def tdiff(e1: Event, e2: Event) -> float:
    return abs(e1.t - e2.t)

orig_cost_matrix = [
    [
        tdiff(e1, e2)
        for e2 in detected
    ]
    for e1 in expected
]
orig_max = max(map(max, orig_cost_matrix))

print('original cost matrix:')
for row in orig_cost_matrix:
    print('[', ', '.join(map(str, row)), ']')

cost_matrix = [
    [
        x if x <= TDIFF_MAX else orig_max + 1
        for x in row
    ]
    for row in orig_cost_matrix
]
print('modified cost matrix:')
for row in cost_matrix:
    print('[', ', '.join(map(str, row)), ']')

row_idx, col_idx = linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix)
for i, j in zip(row_idx, col_idx):
    exp_ev = expected[i]
    det_ev = detected[j]
    td = cost_matrix[i][j]
    if td <= TDIFF_MAX:
        print('matches %s and %s, tdiff: %.3f' % (exp_ev, det_ev, td))
```

Output:

```
original cost matrix:
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 1, 0, 1 ]
modified cost matrix:
[ 4, 4, 4 ]
[ 0, 4, 4 ]
[ 4, 0, 4 ]
matches Event(t=1) and Event(t=1), tdiff: 0.000
matches Event(t=2) and Event(t=2), tdiff: 0.000
```

This works fine, but I don't like this solution for 2 reasons:

1. it looks *ugly and is harder to understand*
2. in "real" application the `expected` and `detected` sets can be quite
   large, and since time difference limit is rather small, most of the matches
   are "unwanted", which makes me think this is rather *inefficient and wastes
   a lot of CPU*.

#### Question:

Is there abetter way to "disable" some possible matches (not necessary using
hungarian algoritm..), which would work better in cases with large data sets
where each `Event` has mostly only 1, 2 or 3 possible matches?

I'm mostly interested in algorithms, so feel free to post solutions in other languages than python or even in pseudocode.

Comment: Before the `scipy` version was added, there was a Python implementation by `munkres`,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075669/hungarian-algorithm-in-python.  It's pure python, so is relatively slow.  Python isn't the best for search types of problems.

Comment: Initially the `scipy` code was the munkres implementation, which you can see in early scipy v 0.18 documentation and [source].  https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.1/scipy/optimize/_hungarian.py#L13-L107.  The current version is "builtin' - compiled, and not as easy to find.

Comment: It's now in the `scipy/optimize/_lsap.c` file.

Comment: @hpaulj that's interesting, but not really relevant to my question - the question is mostly about the algorithm, and how to modify it / use different one, not so much about scipy's implementation..

Comment: I have a feeling this post will be buried under new questions.  I noticed it because I scan [scipy], but have explored `munkres` some years ago, trying speed it up, and looking at `lisp` versions.  But it doesn't look like I posted anything.  [hungarian-algorithm] tag has only 99 posts in a dozen years, and not many watchers.  The current scipy function should be faster, but will be hard to tweak.  I don't know if there's a way or place to post your question that doesn't get buried under a lot of other python/scipy questions.